# Django Models - Relationship between siblings through a child

Tags: django, relationship, children, siblings

How can I list MyModelB objects for each MyModelA, when their relations are not direct, but through MyModelC.

**models.py**

```py
class MyModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class MyModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class MyModelC(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    my_model_a = models.ForeignKey(MyModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    my_model_b = models.ManyToManyField(MyModelB)
```

**my_model_b_list_of_each_c_for_each_a.html**

```
{% for a in object_list %}

{% for c in a.my_model_c_set %}

{% for b in c.my_model_b_set %} # Can I list MyModelBs of each MyModelC?

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what do you mean all mymodelb for mymodel a, they are not related why would they have any correlated listings it seem you did model something wrong. Write some additional details for example data samples and not in a comments but edit the post

Comment: Why not just edit the question and add it instead of adding a comment with apologies.

Comment: I have 3 models (A, B, and C). A and B are siblings. C has a ForeignKey for A, and a ManyToMany field for B. My question is: given a list of A can I loop through B which has no direct relationship with A? Can I list Bs of each A through C?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want fields from your ModelB you can use values_list:

```
ModelA.objects.values_list('modelC__modelB__name', flat=True)
# <QuerySet ['aaa', 'bbb', ...] >
```

otherwise you can get your models in two queries through ids:

```
ModelB.objects.filter(
    id__in=ModelA.objects.values_list(
        'modelC__modelB_id',
         flat=True
    )
)
# <QuerySet [<ModelB (1)>, <ModelB(2)]>
```

Also, if you want your ModelC to be represent a Many to Many with extra data you can use [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).